# Brace initialization difference betweein {} and {0} in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, compilation

Some couple years ago I read that using {} and {0} to initialize POD's had some subtle differences in c++ where one could introduce pessimization in your code.

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC dsd = {};
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC dsd2 = { 0 }:
```

While I know that {0} is certainly something inherited from c and that {} is something that was introduced in c++11, both are supposedly translated during compilation to the same memset() call:

```
memset(&dsd, 0, sizeof(dsd));
```

Yet one of the 2 brace initialization styles did something where memory initialization was unaligned, does anyone care to tell which style is better and why?

Comment: Before you go any further, please hop over to godbolt and see for yourself what these things actually do. Feel free to set up a test structure instead of D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC.

Comment: That use of `{}` has been around at least since C++03.

Comment: Have a look at this page http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization

Comment: If you have more zeros than variables to initialize, you'll get a diagnostic.  If you have fewer zeros, the compiler treats it as if there were enough zeros to initialize all members.

Comment: "{} is something that was introduced in c++11", no.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it calls for **guessing** about what issue you might have encountered, based on broad hints and associations.

Comment: Sorry, I'm kinda new to programming, guess I needed to investigate further and properly before asking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax that you refer to is called [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

> If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members or initializer list is completely empty, the remaining members are value-initialized

Since value initialization of a POD is same as zero-initialization, there is no difference between the two syntaxes that you show.

This has been the case even prior to C++11 - the empty initializer list was not something it introduced. Since C++11, the syntax has become allowed for non-POD's as well. Aggregate initialization is now a special case of this new list initialization.

Comment: But `{}` is default aggregate initialization and `{0}` is zero aggregate initialization.

Comment: @Nikos There is no such thing as "default aggregate initialisation" or "zero aggregate initialisation". Given an aggregate, both of those syntaxes are aggregate initialisation. `{}` has no initialiser for any member so all members are value initialised, while `{0}` has initialiser for the first member which is copy initialised from the literal 0 and the rest of the members are value initialised. Both copy initialisation from literal 0 and value initialisation have effectively same behaviour as zero initialisation.

Comment: "for the first member" I think it's for all members isn't it? `{0}` just initializes everything in the `class`/`struct` to `0`, doesn't it? And `{}` just performs default initialization/construction. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Nikos The `0` in `{0}` is initialiser for the first member. `{0, 0}` would initialise two members. `{1}` would initialise first member to 1. Rest of the members that do not have an initialiser are value initialised. Which for fundamental types is zero initialisation. `{}` doesn't have initialiser for any member, so all members are value initialised (zero initialised in case of fundamental types).

Answer (score -7):

Both versions are "something introduced in C++11". Brace initialization is "just" a way to call constructors. E.g. `D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC dsd = {};` calls the default constructor, while `D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC dsd2 = { 0 };` calls the one, that can be called with `const int` as the only parameter. Neither of them translates to anything similar to `memset(&dsd, 0, sizeof(dsd));` unless one of your constructors does so.

If you have the implicitly declared default constructor, it will simply call the default constructor for every element of that `struct`. The default constructor of built in types does nothing, so the memory will not be set to zero.

For those `struct`s, that have no constructor defined and only public members, and some more limitations, that boil down to C `struct`s, you also get [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). That is basically what you expect coming from C. Anyway, `D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC dsd2 = { 0 };` is not equivalent to `memset(&dsd, 0, sizeof(dsd));`, because the compiler might add padding to the class for whatever reason, and, of course, the type of the field might implement something completely different in its constructor.

OK, now which one is better, of course depends on what you try to achieve. If you are handling C `struct`s, I'd prefer the second, because you will not get an uninitialized value. But please forget any assumptions about `memset()`, or the like. Look at the constructors instead.

Comment: No, both versions were available at least since C++03. OP is talking about PODs, so even the semantics predate C++11.

Comment: Well, C++11 changed them to do something new (call constructors that accept `initializer_list`) but that syntax had behavior before C++11

Comment: The OP specified he's talking about POD initialization, so constructors are not in the picture.

Comment: @aschepler I think, I covered both, because I tried to give a more comprehensive answer. Aggregate initialization actually is, what he was looking for, but that is not equivalent with his `memset()` call as well.

Comment: **−1** “Both versions are "something introduced in C++11"”, no. And so on for just about every sentence and part of sentence.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf well, yes, they are. For C structs the semantic was more or less "like C" in C++98 and is now explicitly a C++ semantic with C++11, that fit into the rest of C++11s brace initialization definition. So in a way, they are new in C++11.

Comment: @cdonat: Your argument is purely associative. Engineering is not like that. The actual syntax used is not new to C++11, even though there is *similar looking* syntax introduced in C++11.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf my resoning is not about the syntax, but about the definitions in the standard. Just because it looks and mostly behaves the same with C++11 as with C++98 doesn't mean, that it is the same. Yes, the syntax was available before as well, but it had subtly different semantics.

Comment: No. I'm sorry. Does it help to know that [`D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476253(v=vs.85).aspx) is a POD type?